# After update target from 2.2 to 4.2.2 ,My App can't open

Tags: android, target

When I update my android app target form 2.2 to 4.2.2
and update the manifest.xml file

My app can't open anymore .
there is some Native code error info in my logcat.

here is the logs:
I don't know what happend

```
    06-25 19:41:09.229: I/DEBUG(4120): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
06-25 19:41:09.229: I/DEBUG(4120): Build fingerprint: 'SKY/SKY_IM-A760S/ef33s:4.0.4/IMM76D/S0211228.EF33S_004:user/release-keys'
06-25 19:41:09.229: I/DEBUG(4120): pid: 13302, tid: 13341  >>> com.voice.assistant.main <<<
06-25 19:41:09.229: I/DEBUG(4120): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr deadd00d
06-25 19:41:09.229: I/DEBUG(4120):  r0 00000000  r1 0042def8  r2 00000000  r3 00000000
06-25 19:41:09.229: I/DEBUG(4120):  r4 deadd00d  r5 40b39f68  r6 0000020c  r7 00000001
06-25 19:41:09.229: I/DEBUG(4120):  r8 41654e28  r9 005e45f0  10 00000008  fp 4c62beb8
06-25 19:41:09.229: I/DEBUG(4120):  ip 00000000  sp 4c62b9e0  lr 40ad54b3  pc 40ad54b2  cpsr 60000030
06-25 19:41:09.229: I/DEBUG(4120):  d0  0000000000000000  d1  0000000000000000
06-25 19:41:09.229: I/DEBUG(4120):  d2  0000000000000000  d3  0000000000000000
06-25 19:41:09.229: I/DEBUG(4120):  d4  0000000000000000  d5  0000000000000000
06-25 19:41:09.229: I/DEBUG(4120):  d6  0000000000000000  d7  3f8000003f800000
06-25 19:41:09.229: I/DEBUG(4120):  d8  3f8000003f800000  d9  0000000000000000
06-25 19:41:09.229: I/DEBUG(4120):  d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
06-25 19:41:09.229: I/DEBUG(4120):  d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
06-25 19:41:09.229: I/DEBUG(4120):  d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
06-25 19:41:09.229: I/DEBUG(4120):  d16 61742061206e6920  d17 7320666f20656c62
06-25 19:41:09.229: I/DEBUG(4120):  d18 0000000000000000  d19 0000000000000000
06-25 19:41:09.229: I/DEBUG(4120):  d20 0000000000000000  d21 0000000000000000
06-25 19:41:09.229: I/DEBUG(4120):  d22 0000000000000000  d23 0000000000000000
06-25 19:41:09.229: I/DEBUG(4120):  d24 e8e8e8e8e8e8e9ef  d25 eaeaeaeaeaeaebf1
06-25 19:41:09.229: I/DEBUG(4120):  d26 ececececececedf2  d27 ffffffffffffffff
06-25 19:41:09.229: I/DEBUG(4120):  d28 0100010001000100  d29 0100010001000100
06-25 19:41:09.229: I/DEBUG(4120):  d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
06-25 19:41:09.229: I/DEBUG(4120):  scr 80000012
06-25 19:41:09.259: E/MediaPlayerService(144): ==========================getDefaultPlayerType- STAGEFRIGHT PLAYER
06-25 19:41:09.279: W/SignalStrength(819): getLTELevel - rsrp:2147483647 snr:2147483647 rsrpIconLevel:-1 snrIconLevel:-1
06-25 19:41:09.279: W/SignalStrength(819): getLTELevel - rssi:99 rssiIconLevel:0
06-25 19:41:09.279: W/SignalStrength(819): getGsmLevel=4
06-25 19:41:09.279: W/SignalStrength(819): getLevel=4
06-25 19:41:09.289: W/QComExtractorFactory(144): Didn't match the sniff <=== status = 5 
06-25 19:41:09.289: W/QComExtractorFactory(144): Didn't match the sniff <=== status = 1 
06-25 19:41:09.289: W/QComExtractorFactory(144): Didn't match the sniff <=== status = 1 
06-25 19:41:09.289: W/QComExtractorFactory(144): Didn't match the sniff <=== status = 1 
06-25 19:41:09.289: E/QComExtractorFactory(144): Sniff FAIL :: coundn't pull enough data for sniffing
06-25 19:41:09.289: E/OMXCodec(144): Attempting to allocate OMX node 'OMX.qcom.audio.decoder.mp3'
06-25 19:41:09.289: E/OMXCodec(144): Attempting to allocate OMX node 'OMX.google.mp3.decoder'
06-25 19:41:09.289: E/OMXCodec(144): Successfully allocated OMX node 'OMX.google.mp3.decoder'
06-25 19:41:09.289: E/OMXCodec(144): configureCodec 
06-25 19:41:09.299: E/AwesomePlayer(144): AudioPlayer created, Non-LPA mode mime audio/mpeg duration 390937
06-25 19:41:09.349: E/AwesomePlayer(144): [SUNNY_WIDEVINE] onCheckAudioStatus(finalStatus : -1011)
06-25 19:41:09.349: E/AwesomePlayer(144): [SUNNY_WIDEVINE] postStreamDoneEvent_l(status : -1011)
06-25 19:41:09.400: I/DEBUG(4120):          #00  pc 000514b2  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmAbort)
06-25 19:41:09.400: I/DEBUG(4120):          #01  pc 000332a4  /system/lib/libdvm.so (_ZNK16IndirectRefTable3getEPv)
06-25 19:41:09.400: I/DEBUG(4120):          #02  pc 00056010  /system/lib/libdvm.so (_Z20dvmDecodeIndirectRefP6ThreadP8_jobject)
06-25 19:41:09.400: I/DEBUG(4120):          #03  pc 00059960  /system/lib/libdvm.so (_Z16dvmCallJNIMethodPKjP6JValuePK6MethodP6Thread)
06-25 19:41:09.400: I/DEBUG(4120): code around pc:
06-25 19:41:09.400: I/DEBUG(4120): 40ad5490 34bcf8d3 ef10f7cd 26001e73 2f01f813  ...4....s..&.../
06-25 19:41:09.400: I/DEBUG(4120): 40ad54a0 42abb152 d0074416 4798e7f8 f7ff4c0a  R..B.D.....G.L..
06-25 19:41:09.400: I/DEBUG(4120): 40ad54b0 7026ffa7 ef06f7cd 2006490c 44794a0c  ..&p.....I. .JyD
06-25 19:41:09.400: I/DEBUG(4120): 40ad54c0 f7cd447a 2000edc2 ee7ef7cd 58e54b05  zD..... ..~..K.X
06-25 19:41:09.400: I/DEBUG(4120): 40ad54d0 2b006c6b e7e9d1e9 deadd00d 0005fb50  kl.+........P...
06-25 19:41:09.400: I/DEBUG(4120): code around lr:
06-25 19:41:09.400: I/DEBUG(4120): 40ad5490 34bcf8d3 ef10f7cd 26001e73 2f01f813  ...4....s..&.../
06-25 19:41:09.400: I/DEBUG(4120): 40ad54a0 42abb152 d0074416 4798e7f8 f7ff4c0a  R..B.D.....G.L..
06-25 19:41:09.400: I/DEBUG(4120): 40ad54b0 7026ffa7 ef06f7cd 2006490c 44794a0c  ..&p.....I. .JyD
06-25 19:41:09.400: I/DEBUG(4120): 40ad54c0 f7cd447a 2000edc2 ee7ef7cd 58e54b05  zD..... ..~..K.X
06-25 19:41:09.400: I/DEBUG(4120): 40ad54d0 2b006c6b e7e9d1e9 deadd00d 0005fb50  kl.+........P...
06-25 19:41:09.400: I/DEBUG(4120): memory map around addr deadd00d:
06-25 19:41:09.400: I/DEBUG(4120): bed4f000-bed70000 [stack]
06-25 19:41:09.400: I/DEBUG(4120): (no map for address)
06-25 19:41:09.400: I/DEBUG(4120): ffff0000-ffff1000 [vectors]
06-25 19:41:09.400: I/DEBUG(4120): stack:
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62b9a0  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62b9a4  400382bd  /system/lib/libc.so
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62b9a8  4006174c  /system/lib/libc.so
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62b9ac  40066878  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62b9b0  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62b9b4  400394c5  /system/lib/libc.so
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62b9b8  40061580  /system/lib/libc.so
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62b9bc  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62b9c0  0000020c  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62b9c4  00000001  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62b9c8  41654e28  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62b9cc  400382db  /system/lib/libc.so
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62b9d0  40b34fb8  /system/lib/libdvm.so
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62b9d4  4c62bbe3  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62b9d8  df0027ad  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62b9dc  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120): #00 4c62b9e0  00380c80  [heap]
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62b9e4  6c756e28  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62b9e8  0000296c  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62b9ec  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62b9f0  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62b9f4  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62b9f8  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62b9fc  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62ba00  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62ba04  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62ba08  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62ba0c  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62ba10  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62ba14  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62ba18  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62ba1c  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62ba20  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62ba24  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62ba28  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62ba2c  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62ba30  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62ba34  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62ba38  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62ba3c  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62ba40  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62ba44  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62ba48  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62ba4c  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62ba50  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62ba54  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62ba58  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62ba5c  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62ba60  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62ba64  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62ba68  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62ba6c  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62ba70  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62ba74  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62ba78  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62ba7c  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62ba80  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62ba84  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62ba88  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62ba8c  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62ba90  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62ba94  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62ba98  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62ba9c  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62baa0  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62baa4  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62baa8  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62baac  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bab0  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bab4  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bab8  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62babc  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bac0  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bac4  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bac8  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bacc  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bad0  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bad4  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bad8  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62badc  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bae0  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bae4  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bae8  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62baec  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62baf0  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62baf4  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62baf8  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bafc  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bb00  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bb04  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bb08  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bb0c  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bb10  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bb14  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bb18  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bb1c  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bb20  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bb24  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bb28  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bb2c  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bb30  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bb34  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bb38  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bb3c  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bb40  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bb44  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bb48  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bb4c  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.410: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bb50  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.420: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bb54  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.420: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bb58  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.420: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bb5c  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.420: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bb60  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.420: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bb64  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.420: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bb68  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.420: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bb6c  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.420: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bb70  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.420: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bb74  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.420: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bb78  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.420: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bb7c  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.420: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bb80  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.420: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bb84  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.420: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bb88  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.420: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bb8c  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.420: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bb90  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.420: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bb94  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.420: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bb98  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.420: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bb9c  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.420: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bba0  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.420: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bba4  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.420: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bba8  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.420: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bbac  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.420: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bbb0  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.420: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bbb4  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.420: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bbb8  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.420: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bbbc  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.420: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bbc0  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.420: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bbc4  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.420: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bbc8  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.420: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bbcc  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.420: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bbd0  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.420: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bbd4  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.420: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bbd8  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.420: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bbdc  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.420: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bbe0  00000000  
06-25 19:41:09.420: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bbe4  8aa1e093  
06-25 19:41:09.420: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bbe8  00000007  
06-25 19:41:09.420: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bbec  00000001  
06-25 19:41:09.420: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bbf0  1d30001d  
06-25 19:41:09.420: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bbf4  40ab72a8  /system/lib/libdvm.so
06-25 19:41:09.420: I/DEBUG(4120): #01 4c62bbf8  1d30001d  
06-25 19:41:09.420: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bbfc  00000007  
06-25 19:41:09.420: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bc00  00000001  
06-25 19:41:09.420: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bc04  005e4688  [heap]
06-25 19:41:09.420: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bc08  40b34fb8  /system/lib/libdvm.so
06-25 19:41:09.420: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bc0c  005e45e0  [heap]
06-25 19:41:09.420: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bc10  1d30001d  
06-25 19:41:09.420: I/DEBUG(4120):     4c62bc14  40ada013  /system/lib/libdvm.so
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your emulator target version.